# Facebook "Recent Activity" from Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am developing a public website with a FaceBook login. Once the user has logged in to the facebook, i want to post my website's URL with thumbnail to his facebook newsfeed "Has read : URL"

I am new to facebook integration. How can i achieve this from my asp.net application ?
Right now, i have added two iframes LIKE and Recent Activity. I am able to see the post that i liked. But how can i post the URL which is read by me ? Thanks.

Note : For testing purpose i have used www.yahoo.com in the iframe.

Below source code is taken from

http://www.abelski.com/courses/facebookplugins/abelski_facebook_plugins_page.html

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?site=sg.news.yahoo.com&width=300&height=300&header=true&colorscheme=light&font=arial&recommendations=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsg.news.yahoo.com&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an Open Graph Action specifically the [news.read](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read) action for an [article](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#article) object. You will need to set up an application that integrates this.

Each of your pages will need to have the meta tags conforming to an article object as defined as

```
<html>
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
                  article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
     <meta property="fb:app_id"               content="YOUR_APP_ID"> 
     <meta property="og:type"                 content="article"> 
     <meta property="og:url"                  content="URL of this object">
     <meta property="og:site_name"            content="Name of site hosting article">
     <meta property="og:image"                content="URL to an image">
     <meta property="og:title"                content="Name of article">
     <meta property="og:description"          content="Description of object"> 
     <meta property="article:published_time"  content="DateTime"> 
     <meta property="article:modified_time"   content="DateTime"> 
     <meta property="article:expiration_time" content="DateTime">
     <meta property="article:author"          content="URL to Author object">
     <meta property="article:section"         content="Section of article">
     <meta property="article:tag"             content="Keyword">
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- main article body -->
</body>
</html>
```

And your action in JavaScript will need to be set up as

```
function postRead()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/news.reads',
        'post',
        { article: 'http://yoursite.com/articlepage.html' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Read was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
```

Read more at the [Open Graph Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)